# How to retrieve permission information from SSISDB packages?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve permission information from packages stored in the SSISDB, but I haven't found a satisfying solution yet. My experience with SSIS is limited, which might be why I'm struggling to make progress.

As far as I understand, permissions might be stored directly within the packages, but I'm unsure how to efficiently extract this information. I've tried a few approaches to access these details but haven't been successful so far.

Does anyone have experience with querying permission information from SSISDB packages? Are there specific system tables or views I might have overlooked, or particular queries that could be used for this purpose? Any guidance or direction you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what permission information you mean. An SSIS package may or may not make a connection somewhere, in which case it may or may not need credentials to establish that connection. If that's the information you're referring to, that's not something that's queryable. Otherwise, if you're referring to the database permissions for users, such as to execute SSIS packages for example, then that's a different story, and those aren't stored within the packages. Those are stored at the database level. Please clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello J.D. - I think i want the second one.

Comment: @SettusBlake, if you want to know what users have permissions to execute SSIS packages, edit your question to specify that instead of burying the actual question in comments.

Comment: @DanGuzman Ok, i thought i did. English is not my native language. I try to be careful and explicit in the future.